# Alexa For Business Private Skill Doesn't Appear for Inclusion in Routine

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have successfully published a private skill via an alexa for business organization.

As stated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/a4b/latest/ag/manage-users.html the A4B users have access to the private skills in the organization for use on their own devices.

Indeed, I am able to locate and enable the skill in my Alexa app under "Skills & Games" > "Private". However, when I try to include the enabled skill in a routine, it is not found in the "Add Action" > "Skills" > "Your Skills" menu..

In fact, I was able to somehow make it appear for inclusion in a routine once (and successfully initiated the skill via the routine as well). However, I now am trying to do it again and to no avail. Whatever I do, I cannot make it show up in the routine menu.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow after i added the skill to a skill group in Alexa For Business, it was available to users for adding in a routine.... not sure why.